# datomic join query execution and metadata

Tags: datomic

In java (through JDBC driver) when I execute a sql join query for T1(a, b) and T2(x, y) I get an output that contains joined record J(a, b, x, y). Along with this I also get metadata that tells me that in joined record J fields "a" and "b" came from table T1 and fields "x" and "y" came from table T2.

My question is, when I run datomic join query in java, do I also get this kind of metadata information that tells me which field in joined record belongs to which input table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datomic does not have tables. It is like a triple store. with time axis built in.

The triple is entity-attribute-value. So, you can include the matched entities in your output, along with attributes and values.

For example, in your database are triples:

```
[joe :likes :pizza]
[joe :favorite-color :gray]
[joe :name "joe"]
[jane :likes :pizza]
[jane :favorite-color :blue]
[jane :name "jane"]
```

joe and jane are entities (which are things having a unique identifier and to which you attach attributes), :likes, :name and :favorite-color are attributes and :pizza, :grey and :blue are values.

a query to find who likes pizza and also has favorite-color gray

```
(d/q '[:find ?person
       :where
       [?person :likes :pizza]
       [?person :favorite-color :gray]]
       db)
```

the result here will be a list of entities, in this case, just `joe`. from that entity you can navigate to all its attributes (name,likes etc). There's not much point in this query but you can return any variable, which can be an entity attribute or value.

I'll stop short here as Datomic has great tutorials along with the official docs.

Comment: But then how do I represent SQL table record in datomic? I guess there will be a concept of primary key based on which we can retrieve record (multiple columns belonging to a record with same primary key) equivalent entity in datomic?

Comment: fleshed out the answer a bit more. but really just thinking an hour on a tutorial is what would help most.

Comment: Thanks for detailed info. Actually I did look at datomic doc but got confused by that. I think your explanation has answered my question. Now I understand that I can include "primary key" or even "tablename" / "dbname" of SQL as one of the attributes of entity, though having "tablename" as attribute for every entity (or record of table) will be repeatative

Comment: Hi Henry, in above case if joe belonged to table T1 (in SQL sense) i.e. [joe :table :T1] and jane belonged to table T2 i.e. [jane :table :T2], then I guess if I want to get all entities/records that belong to table T1 and likes "pizza", then I have to put that as a condition? as in SQL sense two tables may have attributes with same name and if this data is put in datomic then we need to distinguish between them based on table attribute?

Comment: that's one way, yes. or have 2 attributes :table1/likes, :table2/likes.

Comment: urgh. submitted again without finishing... so if you had many likes attributes that has downsides if you also want to reason about liking without caring about table.